# Filtering data for more visualization of data in react-chartjs-2 when you have lot of array element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I want to get proper visualized data on my chart, but it is messing up because there is 1000 of array element. I don't want to reduce the data but actually to get proper visualization because in x-axis of graph it is showing NaN values.

```
fetch("./data.json")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        for (const dataObj of data) {
          empSal.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity));
          empAge.push(parseInt(dataObj.start_year));
        }.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

(1000) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
```

[image]

sample data(data.json):

```
 [
        {
            "end_year": "",
            "intensity": 6,
            "sector": "Energy",
            "topic": "gas",
            "insight": "Annual Energy Outlook",
            "url": "http://www.eia.gov/outlooks/aeo/pdf/0383(2017).pdf",
            "region": "Northern America",
            "start_year": "",
            "impact": "",
            "added": "January, 20 2017 03:51:25",
            "published": "January, 09 2017 00:00:00",
            "country": "United States of America",
            "relevance": 2,
            "pestle": "Industries",
            "source": "EIA",
            "title": "U.S. natural gas consumption is expected to increase during much of the projection period.",
            "likelihood": 3
        },
```

....

want output as :[image]

Comment: show some sample of data ......

Comment: May i know for which properties of above you are trying to plot for `(intensity and start_year)` ?

Comment: yes intensity vs start_year

Comment: so there is an empty value for `start_year` in data , would you want to filter it out and show ?

Comment: yes kind of.. want only start_year data which have values

Comment: check my answer if its useful

Comment: offcus it is useful but I am trying to implement in my project but getting confuse

Comment: could you explain more on what you are confused of ..

Comment: replied in chat room .. please check

Answer (score 1):

You could [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `data` array having both `start_year` and `intensity` and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for both the values :

```
const intensity = data.filter(el => el.intensity && el.start_year).map(val => val.intensity);
const year = data.filter(el => el.intensity && el.start_year).map(val => val.start_year);
```

Using this two you could draw a graph as per your req

sample data filtered example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lxo8mh6/6/)